# javascript closure not working as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery

see the first code:

```
 var count = 0;
 (function addLinks() {
   var count = 0;//this count var is increasing

   for (var i = 0, link; i < 5; i++) {
     link = document.createElement("a");
     link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;

     link.onclick = function () {
       count++;
       alert(count);
     };

     document.body.appendChild(link);
   }
 })();
```

When the link gets clicked the counter variable keeps on increasing for each link element. This is the expected result.

Second:

```
var count = 0;
$("p").each(function () {
  var $thisParagraph = $(this);
  var count = 0;//this count var is increasing too.so what is different between them .They both are declared within the scope in which closure was declared

  $thisParagraph.click(function () {
    count++;
    $thisParagraph.find("span").text('clicks: ' + count);
    $thisParagraph.toggleClass("highlight", count % 3 == 0);
  });
});
```

Here the closure function is not working as expected. On each click on the paragraph element, the counter `var` is increased but that increment is not displayed on click on second paragraph element? What is the reason for this? Why is this happening? The count variable is not increasing for each paragraph element.

Comment: The function you pass to `.click()` is itself a closure, and one of the very first things you do is set the local variable `count` to `0` inside it; the value of `count` is never going to be anything else because you've explicitly told it to always be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean:

```
var count = 0;
$("p").each(function() {
   var $thisParagraph = $(this);
   //var count = 0; //removed this count, as it re-inits count to 0
   $thisParagraph.click(function() {
   count++;
   $thisParagraph.find("span").text('clicks: ' + count);
   $thisParagraph.toggleClass("highlight", count % 3 == 0);
  });
});
```

Comment: but both the count variable(first and second code) are declared within the function in above code

Comment: @MaizerePathak: the first code sample, while declaring the count variable twice as well, has it declared **outside** the loop, while the second example has it delcared **inside** the loop. therefore in the first example the count is not overwritten with each iteration. Unlike the second example in which count is overwritten in every iteration.

Comment: It doesn't re-init count to 0. It shadows the outer count variable, so that each click callback has an independent count and cannot touch the outer count.